# Talend for Master Data Management

Tags: bigdata, etl, talend, master-data-management

I am working on a project to extract **Master Data** from a Database that gathers data from many departments, and this should be done using Talend.
I did some researches to understand what is Master Data exactly and I have some modest experience in working with Talend, the problem is how to detect unchangeable data (Master Data) ?
I can check dates, but what dates exactly? taking example of a sales department, I work based on order date or delivery date and see if the columns keep their values for a long time, but that doesn't sounds right because:

1. First of all, the values can be updated but not dates.
2. Secondly, this rule will work only if the database deals with transactions, but if a column has a distinct values this solution won't work, even though if it is a Master Data.
3. It is easy to deal with it manually and analyze type of column and then decide if it is a master data or not, but this process should be automated.

I hope my idea is clear and I did clarify the problem I am facing, any peace of advise can really help me a lot, if you have any other method in mind which is better, be my guest!

Comment: Hi - what do you think master data is? Why do you think it doesn't change?

Comment: That's the first impression I had, for example employees data is unlikely to be changed during time, that's why I assumed that time will help to identify it, but the biggest question I got is about input columns, should I choose them myself or even that process should be up to the job?